# TSQL Finding Data in a Stuffed comma separated string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I have a query that is not pretty by any means. Its pretty dynamic and is the way it is due to its use case on my application. In short, it allows a user to choose fields they want to see on a report, along with defining the logic (WHERE Clause) and finally which order they want to sort in.

To make this easier, I created a view of all the data that was possible to be included in a report. This way, its just selecting the fields the user wants and querying the view.

I have run into an instance now where instead of just single data points, I have some `1:many` situations. An example is a list of impacted countries. In my view, it is a comma separated list `United States, United Kingdom, Etc`. This data is just stuffed and comma separated in the views creation.

**The Question**

When creating this, I had the intentions of just using an `IN` statement on the data. I then realized that `IN` is only a table function and cant be used on a string of data.

Is there a way to take a value and compare it against a comma separated string of data?

I was trying to create an SQL Fiddle but the site keeps crashing on me.

```
CREATE TABLE Test (country varchar(100), account INT);
INSERT INTO Test ('United States, United Kingdom', '123');
INSERT INTO Test ('United States', '123567');
INSERT INTO Test ('United States, China, Japan', '123567');

-- Trying to find all the rows where `United States` is in the country column.
```

I have tried using `LIKE %country%` however this doesn't function the same as `IN` as I get data back that I don't need if part of the country is in another country name.

Is there any type of function that can be created that acts as an `IN` statement where I can test a value against a comma separated string?

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect a behavior more like the `IN-clause`. Your "Ireland" and "Northern Ireland" will be handled correctly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Test
WHERE ' ' + country + ',' LIKE '% United States,%'
```

This will avoid returning countries that containing another country name in them.

As mentioned by @BenJaspers , Ireland and Nothern Ireland will be an exception so you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM Test
WHERE ',' + country + ',' LIKE '%, United States,%'
   OR ',' + country + ',' LIKE '%,United States,%'
```

Comment: That only partially works. If we take Ireland and Northern Ireland, then searching for Ireland still returns both. You have to check that there is either a comma or nothing before the string `LIKE 'United States,%' OR LIKE '%, United States,%'`

Comment: @BenJaspers You are correct, couldn't think of an example in my head to test all exceptions:)

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (country varchar(100), account INT);
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES('United States, United Kingdom', '123');
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES('United States', '123567');
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES('United States, China, Japan', '123567');
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES('Ireland, United States, Japan', '123567');
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES('Northern Ireland, China, Japan', '123567');

DECLARE @SearchCountry VARCHAR(100)='Ireland';

WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT account 
          ,country
          --The string will be splitted at its commas and is returned as XML in parts
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(country,', ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS CountrySplitted
    FROM #Test
)

SELECT * 
FROM MyCTE
--the first part of the xml is evaluated (may be with LIKE too)
WHERE CountrySplitted.exist('/x[text()=sql:variable("@SearchCountry")]')=1

DROP TABLE #Test;
```

Comment: This may help me get pretty close. Instead of a variable, how can I search by a value in the following line? `sql:variable("@SearchCountry")`

Comment: @SBB Just replace this with "Your value" (double quotes)

Comment: I tried, gave me an error about SQL vars needing the @ sign. I just took off sql:variable and used text()="My Value"

Comment: The above mentioned comment is now resolved. Still trying to get your answer incorporated into my scenario. Does xpath offer anyway to test against multiple values?  `field.exist('/data/val[text()=("var1, var2")]')=1`

Comment: @SBB, What you can do is `field.exist('/data/val[text()="var1" or text()="var2"]')=1` The XML method `exist()` is built with the goal to stop on the first hit. This should be the fastest possible solution (as long as you keep your data in XML)

Comment: @SBB, If my answer helped you to solve your issue it would be kind to vote it up and than to set it as accepted answer. Thx!